# An equivalent expression of Cauchy Criterion?

Tags: convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

For a sequence $\{a_n\}$, if
$$
\forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists N>0, \forall k \in \mathbf{N}, \ |a_{N+k}-a_N|<\epsilon \ 
$$
Then $\{a_n\}$ converges and hence is a Cauchy sequence.

Now how about changing the inequality above to $|a_{N+k}-a_N|< a_{N+k}\cdot \epsilon$, or equivalently $|\frac{a_N}{a_{N+k}} - 1| < \epsilon$? Does the sequence still converge?

Comment: The second sentence seems reversed: the property you define implies being a Cauchy sequence, and therefore a convergent one (if the space is complete). Not the other way around — or did I miss something?

Comment: the equivalent statement you make assumes $a_{N + k} > 0$ - just saying, be careful

Comment: @Did: Yes, this is a too much shortened version of a comment about "it" being a not very useful criterion. Will delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the sequence still converge?

Yes. Assume the criterion in the question holds and, for every $n\geqslant1$, let $N_n$ such that, for every $j\geqslant i\geqslant N_n$, $|a_i-a_j|\leqslant a_j/2^n$. 
Then, for every $j\geqslant N_1$, $\frac23a_{N_1}\leqslant a_j\leqslant2a_{N_1}$, hence $(a_k)$ is bounded. 
Furthermore, for every $n\geqslant1$, for every $j\geqslant i\geqslant N_n$, $a_i\leqslant(1+2^{-n}) a_j$ and $(1-2^{-n})a_j\leqslant a_i$ hence
$(1-2^{-n})\limsup a_k\leqslant\liminf a_k$. Thus, $(a_k)$ converges.

Note that the condition
$$
\forall \epsilon>0, \ \exists N>0, \forall k \geqslant0, \ |a_{N+k}-a_N|<a_N\cdot\epsilon,
$$
also implies convergence (the proof is similar).

Comment: Thanks. But for the last step, what does the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ argument come from?

Comment: If $\limsup a_k=\alpha$ and $\liminf a_k=\beta$, consider $i\geqslant N_n$ and $j\geqslant i$, first such that $a_i\approx\alpha$ and $a_j\approx\beta$, and then the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

You second proposition is actually only defined *if the sequence is always non-zero after some $n$*. Otherwise, if it takes value $0$ infinitely often, then you cannot even write the criterion you suggest.

As André Nicolas pointed out, for the first one, take $0 < \alpha < 1$, and set $a_n\stackrel{\rm{}def}{=} a^n$. It does converge, but your criterion would imply that
$$
\forall k\in\mathbb{N},\quad |a^k-1|\leq a^k\varepsilon
$$
the LHS goes to 1, the RHS to $0$. So your criterion would not be even allow you to conclude for rather elementary sequences...

In both cases, regardless of whatever it still implies convergence, the criterion would not be a very good tool to use.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the non-zero condition should be considered. In fact, in my original problem, terms of sequence is a partial sum of a series of all positive terms. Yes, it seems this is not a good criterion from your example. I was doing an exercise (3.11 b)in Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin, trying to prove $\sum \frac{a_n}{s_n}$ converges implies $\sum a_n$ converges.